# Magento upgrade problem Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.4

I upgraded from Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.0

And now I'm getting the following error when running the indexer.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Api\DefaultStockProviderInterface in /app/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
```

If I disable Magento_InventoryIndexer then the indexer works again but doesn't actually index.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, you had successfully updated `app/lib/internal/Magento` folder? The issue in this folder which is not updated compares the current files with M2.4.0.

Comment: Make sure the module is active. Also, make sure the interface and its concrete class implementation exist. Also, make sure there is a preference for the interface in the code. I think its just not enabled bc thats native Magento class.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson which module is active? How can make sure those classes exist? I don't want to change any of the magento core files. How do I make sure there is a preference for the interface in code?

Comment: @HardikVisa the app/lib/internal/Magento was updated yes. I just did it again to make sure and no changes were show in my repo.